# Average area of intersection between two regular n-sided polygons

Tags: integration, geometry

I want to find the average area of intersection between two regular polygons constructed as such: we uniformly choose any random point $M$ on the interior of the first n-sided polygon and reflect the entire polygon about $M$, so in the figure below the center $O$ of the first polygon becomes $O'$. I want to find the integral of this area over all possible points $M$ and divide it by the area, which if I'm not mistaken gives the average area. My figure below is not so accurate, but the overlapping area should be symmetric across the perpendicular bisector of $OO'$.

I assume that the apothem of the polygon is 1. Using numerical methods I got the value of $\frac{A}{4}$, where $A$ is the area of the polygon. However, I want a proof of this for all values $n\geq3$. I do not know whether there exists a closed form formula to calculate the area of the intersection, but that might help in calculating the integral. The integral could also be split over $2n$ symmetrical triangular areas within the polygon. Other than that, I have no idea how to start proving this, or whether a proof even exists.

Edit: After reconsidering the problem requirements, I exclusively want a non-recursive formula for the intersection area, or a confirmation that it is impossible to find.

[image: Dark area of intersection between polygons is what we want to find.]

Comment: Make $OO'$ vertical and taking $2$-dimensional integral?

Comment: @zkutch What does making $OO'$ vertical mean?

Comment: As you alluded to, we only need to average the integral values for $M$ only within one of the $2n$ symmetrical triangles that compose the polygon. Due to symmetry, this average should be same as if you averaged over the entire polygon. Also the integral value for any point $M$ is equal to twice the area of the polygon segment (which does not contain $O$) formed by drawing a line perpendicular to $OM$

Comment: As $n$ tends to $\infty$, the $n$-polygon tends to a circle. So you can validate your numerical observation of $\frac{A^2}{4}$ at least by theoretically proving it for the circle using chords and trigonometry.

Comment: Another way to phrase your problem: "If you draw a line randomly through an $n$-polygon, splitting it, what is twice the expected (i.e. average) area of the smaller segment?"

Comment: @TonyMathew I have verified the proposition for a circle and a square, which is how I came to guess $\frac{A^{2}}{4}$ in the first place. As for your other comment, I do not believe these are equivalent for odd $n$. Consider a segment of a triangle formed by a line segment parallel to an edge, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146697/discussion-between-tony-mathew-and-wjch).

Comment: @TonyMathew For some reason chat does not let me post. I proved theoretically for both square and circle because those two were far easier than the rest. As for other polygons, I did a MC simulation with approx. 10 million iterations to show that my conjecture was almost certainly correct. The derivations for circle and square are relatively easy as the area of the overlaps could be expressed simply, and the bounds of integration were easy to choose. For other polygons, I'm currently attempting a proof using complex coordinates and the shoelace formula. No guarantees that it will work though.

Comment: @wjch Ah, maybe because you're still a new user; that's unfortunate. But great work with the simulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminary comments.**

The area of a planar set $A$ can be written as the integral of its **indicator function**:   $Area(A)= \int i_A(x) dx$.
The area of two overlapping planar sets  can be written in terms of indicator functions as $Area(A\cap B)=\int i_A(x)\  i_B(x) dx$.  In these integrals, $dx =dx_1 \ dx_2$ denotes planar area measure. Note that under the vector change of variables $y= 2 x$, the  planar area measure transforms as $ dy= dy_1  \ dy_2=  (2 dx_1) (2 dx_2)= 4 dx$.

When we translate set $B$ by the vector $y$,  the overlapping area of the two  translated sets is $ \int i_A(x) i_B(x-y) \ dx$. If the set $B'$ denotes  the reflection of $B$ through the origin, this  latter integral is also equal to $\int i_{B'}(y-x) i_A(x) dx$, which  is called the **convolution** of the  indicator functions of $A$ and $B'$.  The final step in the proof below uses a sort of product rule property of convolutions: $\int (f*g) (y) \ dy = \int (\int f(y-x) g(x) dx) dy =(\int f(y) dy ) (\int g(x) dx) =(\int f) (\int g)$.

**Proof of the OP's conjecture**

Note that the reflection of  polygon  $P$ about point $M$ is the translation of the reversed polygon $P'$ through the vector $\vec y=2\vec M$. For each choice of $\vec M$,  the overlap area of the two polygons is

$A( M)= \int_{ x} i_P(  x) i_P'( y- x) d x= (i_P *i_{P'})(y)$.

The average  value of area is defined as

$\overline A=\frac{\int_{M\in P} A(M) dM}{\int_{M\in P} i_P}$ whose denominator is a normalization constant that ensures that the total probability space has measure 1.

Note that $dM= \frac{1}{4} dy$ since $y= 2M$.

Thus  the numerator in the expression that defines $\overline A$ satisfies $\int_M A(M) dM= \frac{1}{4}\int A(M) dy =\frac{1}{4}   \int_{y} (i_P *i_{P'})(y) dy=\frac{1}{4} \int(i_P))( \int  i_{P'})$  by the product rule.

After dividing by the normalization constant, we see that
$\overline A=\frac{1}{4} \int i_{P'}$, which can be  recognized as one fourth of the area of $P$.  QED.

Comment: Edited to clarify that point.

Comment: Not very familiar with vector calculus, but shouldn't dy be twice of dM?

Comment: No because for example doubling all vectors in the unit square creates a $2\times 2$ square whose area is 4.

Comment: In general a multivariable change of coordinates $(y_1,  y_2) = (f(x_1, x_2),  g(x_1, x_2))$ has an associated transformation formula for area involving the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives of the coordinate change: $ dy_1 dy_2 = J dx_1 dx_2$ where $J=| f_xg_y- f_y g_x|$ is  called the Jacobian.